# Change version number of maintenance plan package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, maintenance-plans

We have a Maintenance Plan on SQL 2012 that has been running fine. I made a change to it yesterday using SSMS 2014. When the plan ran last night I got the following error:

> The version number in the package is not valid. The version number
>   cannot be greater than current version number.

The error seems pretty straight forward - because I edited in SSMS 2014, it upgraded the version number and can no longer run on 2012.

I thought I would fix this by opening the maintenance plan in SSMS 2012 and saving it, however when I try to open the plan I now get an error box pop up:

[image: Error Message]

Is there any way that I can edit this maintenance plan to make it work again, or do I need to either recreate it or recover it from a backup?

Comment: Still interested in an answer, but we're going to recreate the maintenance plans in SSMS 2012 (and not use 2014 for it again)